# DNS Server for Ubuntu VPS with low memory usage

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind

I recently purchased an Ubuntu VPS. However my memory is almost completely consumed by mysql and bind9.

Is there any way to use another DNS Server instead of bind9 that consumes less RAM?

Or perchance there is a configuration to lower its memory usage?

Comment: Specify how much memory please and what your appliance is

Comment: How low IS your RAM? You know, a small small VPS - 32mb or 64mb - is not really there to run anything else than a small DNS or some other similar small app.

Comment: its using about 200M, and for my case it is RAM wasting.

Comment: @TomTom, currently my vps have 512M of Ram.

Comment: How much is used by bind, how much by mysql? mysql may want some tuning, but unless your app is tiny, 512mb is small... but then, tell us what uses how much.

Comment: @TomTom, bind using about 200Mb, and mysql with default configuration about 184Mb

Comment: Sounds a little high for bind. I use windowsfor my dns and i have less memory usage including the OS... which is not as small as linux. Why do you run bind anyway? Use an external service or your dns.

Comment: what BIND is used for ? Do you need it at all ?

Comment: @Sandman4, TomTom I just ASK that! do you know any alternate for BIND9?

Comment: @wtayyeb what is the purpose of your DNS server - authoritative, recursive, other ?

Comment: i just want to handle my domain and sub-domains!

Comment: @wtayyeb Then you're looking for "authoritative".  Maybe have a look at PowerDNS?

Comment: Maybe post here your named.conf, and `ps -eF|grep named`

Comment: 200mb for bind is abnormal. I wouldn't talk about replacing bind, but rather about solving some problem which causes bind to be this huge.

Answer (score 1):

SSH will only use RAM when that RAM is not needed for any more important purpose. If you're not actually connecting to it, it should be swapped out as soon as there is any better use for memory. You're trying to solve a problem that's already solved by the operating system's memory management system.

The operating system understands that free RAM is free, that is, that there is no cost associated with using it. It makes no attempt to minimize RAM usage, nor does it generally make any sense for it to do so. Don't worry, the OS is smart enough to use your RAM for the most important purpose at any particular time. If it's letting SSH use the RAM, that's because that is what is best.

Comment: thanks for the try but when I lunch BIND, Mysql and Nginx on the VPS, its stops responding to anything else! because there is no RAM remaining to response, ether to SSH.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enough swap. You need to be able to get the stuff that's not being used out of RAM.

Comment: yes I have no swap. also i dont know how to create a swap on this vps. I am reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103043/how-to-create-swap-partition-on-already-installed-ubuntu) but cant do the trick!